# How does Android choose which small/normal/large resource folder?

Tags: android, android-resources

I've a 7 inch tablet but Android select the `normal/` resource folder, and it's wrong for me.

I found that I can get the diagonal with some calculations:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
Log.d("debug", "Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

When choosing the resource folder, what Android does?

1. **Make this kind of calculation** or
2. **get screen size from *build.prop*?**

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: This comment is not very usefull to my question... Device configuration comes from build.prop or from calculations?