# How to get android device screen size?

Tags: android, android-screen

I have two android device with same resolution

Device1 -> resolution 480x800 diagonal screen size -> 4.7 inches

Device2 -> resolution 480x800 diagonal screen size -> 4.0 inches

How to find device diagonal screen size?

[Detect 7 inch and 10 inch tablet programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055458/detect-7-inch-and-10-inch-tablet-programmatically)

I have used the above link but it gives both device diagonal screen size -> 5.8

Comment: What is your problem then ?

Comment: I want to find programatically diagonal screen size to find which device is

Comment: The code you have tried is the right code as you are getting the diagonal screen size.

Comment: But it gives same diagonal screen size for both the device. Is any other way to calculate diagonal screen size?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

try this code to get screen size in inch

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
double wi=(double)width/(double)dm.xdpi;
double hi=(double)height/(double)dm.ydpi;
double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

Comment: Not getting exact location. if screen size 5.00 inches then get 4.338 value

Comment: `double wi=(double)width/dm.xdpi; double hi=(double)height/dm.ydpi;` is more accurate. According to the docs for DensityMetrics, it gives the exact density, while `dm.densityDpi` can only give certain discrete values. I've verified it working on two devices.

Comment: it doesn't accurate. it returns 4.3" for my 4.7" phone

Comment: If you're getting weird answers (or more importantly your images come out weird because you are using the size to scale stuff), don't forget to use scaledDensity.  See my answer below.

Comment: For SDK 17& above refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55337830/6503228 for accurate screensize

Comment: Returns 5.7" for Google Pixel 2 XL when it is really 6"

Answer (score 12):

This won't work?

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
Log.d("debug", "Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

Comment: Nice copy paste :) Similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589101/how-to-get-screen-size-of-device

Comment: You can post as comment also.

Comment: Funny, i copy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106854/how-does-android-choose-which-small-normal-large-resource-folder?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to multiply the screen size by the scaledDensity if you are doing what I did and change the size of stuff based on the screen size.  e.g.:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y) * dm.scaledDensity;
Log.d("debug", "Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

Note the second last line!   Here's more info the scaledDensity stuff:  [What does DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity actually return in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916490/what-does-displaymetrics-scaleddensity-actually-return-in-android)

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked also mentioned using `getResources().getDisplayMetrics();` to get the correct scaledDensity value.

Comment: * dm.scaledDensity saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

None of the above answers gave correct screen size... But the below method does it right.

```
private String getScreenSize() {
    Point point = new Point();
    ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(point);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width=point.x;
    int height=point.y;
    double wi=(double)width/(double)displayMetrics.xdpi;
    double hi=(double)height/(double)displayMetrics.ydpi;
    double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
    return String.valueOf(Math.round((Math.sqrt(x+y)) * 10.0) / 10.0);
}
```

Note: This works only on API 17 & above.

Comment: I have a 1.5 inch watch and this method returns 5.5

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 public static Boolean isTablet(Context context) {

    if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

      return true;
  }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics();

String screenWidthInPix = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

String screenheightInPix = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: This is a bad method. Thre resources return an inaccurate dpi and resolution.