# Android ViewPager Show Multiple Fragments depending on Screen Size

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How can one display multiple `Fragment`s in a `ViewPager` according to the screen size; if it is a small device, it would display 1 `Fragment` in one screen. If it is a tablet in landscape mode, it would display 2 `Fragment` in a single screen, next to each other. If it is a tablet in portrait mode, it would display 1 `Fragment`?

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your ViewPagerAdapter class, override getPageWidth(). It returns a float (default of 1) with the amount of space each page should take up. Changing this value, for example, to .5f will have two fragments appear in the same window.

```
@Override public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return(1f/simultaneousPages);
}
```

In addition, setOffscreenPageLimit() should be increased. Its default is one, which means now that we show two pages, not enough fragments will be loaded into memory in the background. As a general rule, this should be twice the amount of pages on each screen.

In MainActivity.java (or whatever activity uses your ViewPagerAdapter)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the viewpager in activity_main.xml
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    // Load extra pages into memory for smooth transitions
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2*simultaneousPages);
}
```

To change the view based on screen size, simply change the simultaneousPages variable as appropriate. [More on detecting physical screen sizes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155559/how-to-get-android-device-screen-size)

Note: This method will cause problems with PagerTitleStrip and PagerTabStrip. The "current tab" that appears as selected will show as whatever fragment is the furthest left on your view.

[Alternative solutions and more information.](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)