# How to access the screen properties in a class extending Application

Tags: android, screen

I have my initial

```
public class myapplication extends Application {
}
```

which is starting before any activity is started.

How can I access the getWindowManager() to get screen properties ?

I would like to calculate the screeninches (which I know how to do in general) before I started an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) from resources

```
public class myapplication extends Application {

   public DisplayMetrics getMetrics(){
      return getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(dm);
        System.out.println("Screen width =" + dm.widthPixels);
        System.out.println("Screen height =" + dm.heightPixels);

    }
}
```

and to get screen size in inches
[How to get android device screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155559/how-to-get-android-device-screen-size)